# Is there any alternative for Excel solver in R?

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

We have the below code for solving an optimization problem where we want to maximize sales by applying constraint on profit and no. of items.
We want to apply this profit threshold as a percentage of Revenue generated by 200 items only. 
We have done it by applying a formula on profit using changing variable in Excel Solver using GRGE non-linear algorithm. We want a similar alternative for R.
Is there any way to assign changing variable in R?

**Dataset**

```
item sales profit
A 1200 120
B 5600 45
C 450  00
D 990 -90
E 1000 80
F 560  120
G 500  23
H 2000 350
```

**Code**

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
dataset<-read.csv("Dataset.csv",header=T,na.strings='NA',stringsAsFactors =F)
dataset$keep_flag <-1 

**all the func in LPsolve API**
ls("package:lpSolveAPI")
summary(dataset)

**Passing the parameters**
ncol <- nrow(dataset) 

**you have eight rows that can be picked or dropped from the solution set**
lp_rowpicker <- make.lp(ncol=ncol)
set.type(lp_rowpicker, columns=1:ncol, type = c("binary"))

**checking the model**
lp_rowpicker

**setting objective**
obj_vals <- dataset$Revenue_1hr.Projected
#obj_vals<- dataset[, 2]
obj_vals
set.objfn(lp_rowpicker, obj_vals) 
lp.control(lp_rowpicker,sense='max')

**Adding contraints**

Profit constraint
xt<- (dataset$Profit_1hr.Projected)
add.constraint(lp_rowpicker, xt, ">=", 100)
xt

#No.of items to be kept
xt<- (dataset$keep_flag)
add.constraint(lp_rowpicker, xt, "=", 4)
xt

#model check
lp_rowpicker

#solving equation
solve(lp_rowpicker)

#Maximised revenue
get.objective(lp_rowpicker)

#The one with binary as 1 is our item
dataset$keep_flag<- get.variables(lp_rowpicker)
dataset$keep_flag <- as.data.frame(dataset$keep_flag)
sum(dataset$keep_flag)



final_set <- cbind(dataset,final_flag)
final_set <- final_set[which(final_set$final_flag==1),]

final_set$keep_flag <- NULL
final_set$final_flag<- NULL
```

This code snippet applies the profit threshold on total no. of items rather than applying it on selected items.

**Edit**

This is the model that got created when I ran @Karsten W. code:

```
           C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8         
Maximize  1200  5600   450   990  1000   560   500  2000         
R1         120    45     0   -90    80   120    23   350  >=  100
R2           1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1   =    4
Kind       Std   Std   Std   Std   Std   Std   Std   Std         
Type       Int   Int   Int   Int   Int   Int   Int   Int         
Upper        1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1         
Lower        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

And the output obtained is:

```
    item sales profit
1      A  1200    120
1.1    A  1200    120
1.2    A  1200    120
1.3    A  1200    120
```

The same item is returned four times. I want 4 unique items. Plus I want to apply constraint of profit as a percentage of Sales generated by those 4 items.
By the way, we kept 'keep_flag' for the similar function to what your 'nitems'    is doing. It is a changing variable that takes binary value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems ok to me, except for that the variable names do not fit to the dataset you provided. In particular it is not clear to me what `keep_flag` stands for, is that some sort of preselection?

The profit constraint in your code is applied only the four from the solver selected variabes.

Here is your code, a bit cleaned up.

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

dataset <- data.frame(item=LETTERS[1:8], sales=c(1200, 5600, 450, 990, 1000, 560, 500, 2000), profit=c(120, 45, 0, -90, 80, 120, 23, 350))
nitems <- nrow(dataset)

# make lp   
lprec <- make.lp(0, ncol=nitems)
set.type(lprec, columns=seq.int(nitems), type="binary")

# set objective
lp.control(lprec, sense="max", bb.rule="gap", timeout=30)
set.objfn(lprec, obj=dataset[, "sales"]) 

# constraints
min_rel_profit <- 0.10 # min. 10% profit
add.constraint(lprec, dataset[, "profit"]-min_rel_profit*dataset[,"sales"], ">=", 0) # required profit
add.constraint(lprec, rep(1, nitems), "=", 4)  # four products

print(lprec)
solve(lprec)
dataset[get.variables(lprec)==1,]
```

The profit constraint is derived as follows (`p` is the vector of profits, `s` is the vector of sales, `x` is the decision variable 0/1, all of length `nitems`, `minp` is the minimum relative profit):

- sum(profit) / sum(sales) >= minprofit translates to `p'x/s'x >= minp`
- this is equivalent to `(p - minp s)'x >= 0`

Hence the minimum profit has to appear as part of the coefficients on the LHS.

If you are encountering long solving times, you can finetune the parameters. See `?lp.control.options` for more details. Use `timeout` to set a time limit while testing. For this kind of problem (MIP) the `bb.rule` parameter is helpful. Given your example data, a solution for 9.5% was found in less than one second.

Comment: I ran your code. The model that got created and the output that I got is given in the edited version of my question.

Comment: there was a small error in the last line of code; fixed it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "constraint of profit as a percentage of Sales generated by those 4 items"? In your example, what would the constraint be?

Comment: So i want to give constraint in percentage. If i give x% as my constraint, then the algorithm should select 'n' items(in this case 4) such that [sum(profit of these n items) * 100]/sum(revenue of these n items) >= 'x'

Comment: Thanks a lot. We tried the same thing but with 'min_rel_profit*dataset[,"sales"] in RHS. Does it accept only numeric value in RHS ?

Comment: Edited answer. Yes on the RHS only numeric values are allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot...that was really helpful

Comment: Did that already :D
But i don't have enough reputation points for it to count (started using stack overflow recently)

Comment: The above code is running fine for most of the profit percentages but gets stuck on solve(lprec) on particular percentage values. Like in our case it's running fine for 8, 8.5, 9, 10, 10.5 profit % but gets stuck for 9.5, then I have to terminate the session. I am not able to figure out the reason. Can you help me with it?

Comment: I can not reproduce this, the example data works fine with 9.5%. Are you willing to share your data via personal message?

Comment: Yeah Okay, 
How do i share the data ?

Comment: I sent the data

Thanks for your help

Comment: Edited the answer for tackling long solving times.

Comment: Hey ! A quick question .
When i tried selecting 200 items based on its revenue from 300 items where 150 odd items had same revenue, the lpsolver didnt give us optimized result. 
What can be done to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Maybe put it in a separate question or on orexchange.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at a few and choose the best

LPSolve https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/lpSolve.pdf,
This is a simple linear solver. Its pretty much similar to LPSolve Api but I find it much more easier.

Minqa https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minqa/minqa.pdf
This is a quadriatic solver that works mostly for non linear problems

Gurobi http://www.gurobi.com/products/modeling-languages/r
This is an open source implementation of IBM's CPLEX solver. Very good and competent.

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.